# Receiving error when I try to run my ASP.NET MVC web application after I updated to Bootstrap 5.3.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I just updated my bootstrap to version 5.3.3 using Nuget Package Manager. Now when I run my MVC Web Application my browser says that there is a server error and displays this:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 39: 
Line 40:     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
Line 41:     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
Line 42:     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
Line 43: </body>

Source File: C:\Users\uptown\Documents\Education\Personal Information\Portfolio\C#\WebApplication1\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml    Line: 41
```